# Scope of a variable using setTimeout

Tags: javascript, scope, settimeout

I am happy it works but still a bit confused of what the scope of the "me" variable is in the following code. Using it for a while now but can't figure out why it works.

```
var timer=function(){
    this.timerMember=1;
    this.timerID=0;
    this.startTimer=function(){
        var me=this;
        this.timerID=setTimeout(function(){
            //shares scope with this.startTimer
            //timerMember is 2 here
            console.log(me.timerMember);
            // this is window
            console.log(this);
            // me doesn't exist in window
            console.log(this.me);
        },0);
//  this code gets executed before anonymous
//  timer function
//        clearTimeout(this.timerID);
        this.timerMember++;
    }
}
var t=new timer();
t.startTimer();
```

The anonymous function passed to setTimeout seems to share scope with timer.startTimer yet startTimer is obviously finished when the anonymous function executes (me.timerMemer=2) so when startTimer is done the me variable should be out of scope. Lucky for me JavaScript keeps it until the anonymous function is executed (works on all browsers) but I wonder if this is the right way. Is this behavior by design or just a fortunate accident?

Comment: This is standard JavaScript ["closure" behaviour](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Guide/Closures). (Certainly not an accident.)

Comment: Instead of doing var `var me = this;` you can just do `this.timerID=setTimeout(function(){}.bind(this), 2)` in some cases.

Comment: @PeeHaa: `bind` is a relatively recent feature, not supported until IE 9, Firefox 4.0, etc.

Comment: IE9 ok, but are you really worried firefox **3**? :P Note that FF is currently on v1228 ;)

Comment: @PeeHaa: What does "v1228" mean? Firefox is currently at version 18.0.

Comment: Sense of humour bypass...

Comment: VInstead of .bind I think .apply is more widely supported. Will update code when I have the time. Thank you all for the help

Comment: Ok, leave it like this: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind#Browser_compatibility bind is only supported in IE9 and up.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's by design. It's called a closure.

When a function is defined inside another function, the local variables in the outer function is put in a closure, so that they survive even after the outer function ends. The inner function holds on to the closure so that it can accesses the variables later on.